# How to put a legend in a pie chart on d3.js v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a pie chart that is in need of a legend. The problem is I don't know how to do it. I've tried every tutorial that I can find and it still won't work. Every documentation that I find it's only for v3. Below is my snippet of the code.

I've tried putting a random div on the right side so that the legend will be appended or created inside that div but still won't work.

```js
/** START OF PIE CHART */

var data = [{"region_iso_code":"PH-00","total_up_percentage":97.69},{"region_iso_code":"PH-01","total_up_percentage":99.83},{"region_iso_code":"PH-02","total_up_percentage":97.96},{"region_iso_code":"PH-03","total_up_percentage":99.29},{"region_iso_code":"PH-04","total_up_percentage":98.36},{"region_iso_code":"PH-05","total_up_percentage":98.02},{"region_iso_code":"PH-06","total_up_percentage":96.91},{"region_iso_code":"PH-07","total_up_percentage":99.75},{"region_iso_code":"PH-LAG","total_up_percentage":98.84}]

var svgCirWidth = 600, svgCirHeight = 300, radius = Math.min(svgCirWidth, svgCirHeight) / 2;

const pieContainer = d3.select("#pieChart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", svgCirWidth)
    .attr("height", svgCirHeight);

//create group element to hold pie chart

var g = pieContainer.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + radius + ")");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
    return d.total_up_percentage;
});

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(0);

var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter() //means keeps looping in the data
    .append("g");

arc.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.total_up_percentage);
    })
    .append("text")
    .text("afdaf");

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(0);

arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", (d) => {
        return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text((d) => {
        return d.data.total_up_percentage + "%"
    });

/* END OF PIE CHART */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>

    <!--Lib css-->
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--fontawesome-->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--own css-->
    <style>
        @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

        body {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            background: #fafafa;
        }

        p {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.7em;
            color: #999;
        }

        a,
        a:hover,
        a:focus {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        .navbar {
            padding: 15px 10px;
            background: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .navbar-btn {
            box-shadow: none;
            outline: none !important;
            border: none;
        }


        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        #sidebar {
            min-width: 250px;
            max-width: 250px;
            background: rgb(60, 95, 238);
            color: #fff;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        #sidebar.active {
            margin-left: -250px;
        }

        #sidebar .sidebar-header {
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgb(90, 121, 243);
        }

        #sidebar ul.components {
            padding: 20px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
        }

        #sidebar ul p {
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a {
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            display: block;
        }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #sidebar ul li.active>a,
        a[aria-expanded="true"] {
            color: #fff;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 20px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        ul ul a {
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            padding-left: 30px !important;
            background: #6d7fcc;
        }

        ul.CTAs {
            padding: 20px;
        }

        ul.CTAs a {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.9em !important;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        a.download {
            background: #fff;
            color: #7386D5;
        }

        a.article,
        a.article:hover {
            background: #6d7fcc !important;
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

        #content {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            min-height: 100vh;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
            #sidebar {
                margin-left: -250px;
            }

            #sidebar.active {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

            #sidebarCollapse span {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        /* ---------------------------------------------------
    CHART STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- 

               </style>

    <!--lib js-->

    <!--bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--fontawesome js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

    <!--d3(chart) js-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/">DASHBOARD</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--End of nav.sidebar-->
        </nav>

        <!--Page content-->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!--End of div.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-5">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="pieChart">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of div.row-->
        </div>


    </div>
    <!--End of div.content-->

    </div>
    <!--End of div.wrapper-->

    <!--Lib <script>-->


    <!--own <script>-->

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Mehdi That's my previous question which no one answered...

Comment: @Toastrackenigma I'm not a dupe. I'm just asking for help or what to do.

Comment: Thinking about it now, you shouldn't ask the same question twice, so it is actually a valid duplicate.